# Homekit accessory out of compliance error

Tags: ios, objective-c, homekit

I am working on Homekit based application.

Its used to connect Homekit Accessory Protocol(HAP) enabled accessory(Like LED Light or bridge) and It can get information of accessory, perform various operation on them(Light on/off etc).
Bridge is running on server installed in ubuntu pc.

Firstly iOS app will try to pair to Bridge (Bridge will be connected to non HAP accessory which is basedon zigbee or z-wawe protocol.)
, then iOS app will ask for setup code which is for that specific accessory.

We are working on bridge as well as iOS application.

Apple has provided Homekit Accessory Tester(HAT) app (which is basically perform like iOS app, technically a controller).
I am able to connect to bridge using HAT app by following all process described by apple in MFI documentation.

Now I am facing problem while I am tring to connect to bridge using app, either in iOS simulator or iOS device (8.2)

But is gives error when I try to add accessory to Home from accessory browser with error code **HMErrorCodeAccessoryOutOfCompliance-66**.

Is this because of MFI authentication? Or Anything we are missing? which is require to do while connecting from iOS app.

Answer (score 0):

Typically this would be an accessory characteristic value falling outside of a constraint (such as a max or min range that is acceptable),  or possibly a required characteristic missing for a particular accessory's service.

MFi authentication would be a bridge issue, and not something you'll deal with if you have authentication disabled for a session.  If security is enabled, you'd likely not get past pairing if there was an MFi issue, and wouldn't be able to complete any further paired requests.

My answer won't help you resolve your problem, but it gives you a clue where to look (at your bridge, or at bridged accessories).  You might consider "removing" bridged accessories, and start first with the bridge and make sure it exposes everything required for a bridge (just an Accessory Information Service), and then beyond that any other services it might expose need to be spec compliant.